# Idempotency in MongoDB nested array, possible?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest

I am writing a REST api which I want to make idempotent. I am kind of struggling right now with nested arrays and idempotency. I want to update an item in `product_notes` array in one atomic operation. Is that possible in MongoDB? Or do I have to store arrays as objects instead (see my example at the end of this post)? Is it for example possible to mimic the `upsert` behaviour but for arrays?

```
{
 username: "test01",
 product_notes: [
  { product_id: ObjectID("123"), note: "My comment!" },
  { product_id: ObjectID("124"), note: "My other comment" } ]
}
```

If I want to update the note for an existing product_node I just use the update command and `$set` but what if the `product_id` isn't in the array yet. Then I would like to do an `upsert` but that (as far as I know) isn't part of the embedded document/array operators.

One way to solve this, and make it idempotent, would be to just add a new collection `product_notes` to relate between `product_id` and `username`.
This feels like violating the purpose of document-based databases.

Another solution:

```
{
 username: "test01",
 product_notes: {
  "123": { product_id: ObjectID("123"), note: "My comment!" },
  "124": { product_id: ObjectID("124"), note: "My other comment" } }
}
```

Anyone a bit more experienced than me who have anything to share regarding this?

Comment: what number of comments can be stored with user? mongo version?

Comment: I think I know what you are aiming for. But never mind the schema design and if it is the correct way to model it. I think it will between 10 - 100 products, something like that. The code shown is not the exact project but more of an example of where the problem lies. I have already made a solution with product_notes in its own collection... which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your requirement is that you would like to store unique product ids (array) for an user.

You could create an **composite unique index** on **"username" and "username.product_id"**. So that when the same product id is inserted in the array, you would an exception which you could catch and handle in the code as you wanted the service to be Idempotent.

In terms of adding the new element to an array (i.e. product_notes), I have used Spring data in which you need to get the document by primary key (i.e. top level attribute - example "_id") and then add a new element to an array and update the document.

In terms of updating an attribute in existing array element:-

1. Again, get the  document by primary key (i.e. top level attribute -
   example "_id")
2. Find the correct product id occurrence by iterating the array data
3. Replace the "[]" with array occurrence

   ```
   product_notes.[].note
   ```